# How to obtain a list of all lighttpd servers running and which port each one is listening to?

Tags: lighttpd

I have several lighttpd servers running on an Arch Linux machine, all for local network use only. I want to know which lighttpd server is watching which port.  'ps aux | grep light' lists them all by process id, but provides no clues about port number.  What commands can I use to find out which process id goes with which port?

Comment: @DarenW Use the `lsof` command. See Option #1 [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/) and look for the name of the application followed by the TCP listen address and port for each process.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a command to do the job.

```
ss -4 -l -p -t  -n |  grep light
```

Typical output looks like

```
LISTEN 0      1024         0.0.0.0:3004      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("lighttpd",pid=1475828,fd=3))
LISTEN 0      1024         0.0.0.0:7880      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("lighttpd",pid=252797,fd=3))
```

The "4" may be left off to see IPv6, but for my LAN it's all IPv4. "-l" for LISTEN, "-p" shows port numbers, "-t" for TCP (not UDP) and "-n" shows ports as numbers not meaningful names, though there probably won't be any with user-defined port numbers like 7880 set in lighttp.conf files. Grep filters the lighttpd servers (I don't care about other http servers, if any).

I have never heard of the "ss" command until recently. Maybe I should spend a day reading a Linux system administration guide - things have changed!